What YouTube API can be used to update a Video "Ad Suitability" Settings
I am building a software that can upload YouTube videos using the YouTube APIs and also set all the video settings including the "Ad Suitability" Settings just as it is done when uploading through the YouTube Studio. I Have searched through the YouTube Content ID API and the YouTube Data API but I can't see any resources that shows how to update the settings for a video.
Am wondering if there is no YouTube API for the "Ad Suitability" settings or am I missing something?
I appreciate the insight of anyone with some knowledge about this. Thanks in advance.

If you have read the documentation and searched on the web and you found no information, it's most likely that the feature you're looking for is not available through any API.
You could check on Issue Tracker and see if you get a more official response.
